# Why do network connections hang?

Tags: networking

We've all had the experience: you click on a link, and your browser just... sits there. After 10-15 seconds the page might eventually load, but it's usually the case that if you just stop the page and refresh, the page loads instantly.

What is the technical reason for this? Why does the network connection get stuck in such a way that it can't finish loading the page, but if I stop the request and refresh it is successful almost instantly? Why can't the first connection recover somehow?

I realize that this could be caused by all sorts of things, especially on the server side, but I suspect that in most cases it has to do with the networking stack itself (TCP/IP), so I'm looking for the most generally applicable answer.

Comment: `I'm looking for the most generally applicable answer` - You're not going to find it, because it literally could be anything. To say it's due to something in the network stack itself is to over simplify it (and is stating the obvious). It could be DNS (which is part of the network stack), it could be a routing problem (which is part of the network stack), it could be a layer 2 problem (which is part of the network stack), etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's developer tools to determine where the time is being spent - DNS lookups, time to connect, time to send the request, and time for the server to start and finish sending the response should be broken down there.